# Redux form doesn't pass new value when the value change from null to empty string

Tags: redux, redux-form

I have a custom select component which has a different behavior if it's value is null or an empty string.

To be able to pass a null value to the Field component, I put `format={null}` as per [the documentation](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/field.md/).

In the redux store, my component is correctly initialized with `value: null` and the component `input.value` is also `null`, as expected. When I select the value with the empty string, redux-form correctly dispatch the event `@@redux-form/CHANGE` and the value of my Field correctly change from `null` to `''` but my `input.value` in my component never change and is still `null`.

On the other hand, if I select a non null & non empty string value, then the empty string value (e.g `null` => `'1'` => `''`), the `input.value` is correctly updated and my component correctly render.

Does someone know why doing `null` => `''` doesn't change the `input.value` but `null` => `'a value'` => `''` does ?

Comment: This sounds like your react component receiving `value:null` is deciding not to update when it receives `value:''` as a prop. I would try to force the component to update with the `shouldComponentUpdate()` property.

Comment: I added a `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` which always return true but it doesn't work. The function is not even called.

Comment: That's unfortunate. You might have more success either setting the initial `input:false`. Or you could make another key in your redux state like `form_is_clean:true` which gets changed when the input is focused. I think really the issue is React isn't keying in to the prop changing from one "false" state to another "false" state. You might even try setting the initial state `input:true`... This is an issue in general with JS's loose typing.

Comment: Yes, it was my hunch too. I will try to do more tests today, because I really want to avoid having to do some dirty hack to make it work :/

Comment: I tried with a normal react component that take a props which can be null, an empty string or any string, React do re-render when switching from null to empty string.
The issue is with redux and/or redux-form.